# formula to move the peak freely along the X axis on the chart

Tags: python, math, charts, formula, curve

I draw an exponential chart and now I want to move the peak freely along the X axis.

The center should be like a bell, and the right side like a my current chart but totaly reversed.

How can I do that?

```
import matplotlib
import math
import numpy as np
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

arr_name=[]
arr_value=[]
k=-0.01
for l in range(0,100):
    x=pow(k,2)*np.exp(-k*1.8);
    if (l%10)==0:
        arr_name.append(l/10)
    else:
        arr_name.append("")
    arr_value.append(x)
    k=k+0.05
    print x

y_pos = np.arange(len(arr_name))
plt.figure(figsize=(8,4))
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 8})
plt.subplot(1,1,1)
plt.plot(y_pos, arr_value, '-r')
plt.xticks(y_pos, arr_name)
plt.savefig('/var/www/html/bar/img/test_chart.png')
```

[image: exponential chart]

**update:**

possible solution to draw peak at the center of the chart:

```
for l in range(0,100):
    x=pow(k,5)*np.exp(-k*1.96);
    if (l%10)==0:
        arr_name.append(l/10)
    else:
        arr_name.append("")
    arr_value.append(x)
    if l>50:
        k=k-0.05
    else:
        k=k+0.05
    print x
```

[image]
adding reversibility:

```
arr_value.reverse()
```

[image]

Comment: (I assumed by vertex you mean the peak and by scale you mean axis.) The location of maximum of course depends on that 1.8 factor inside the `exp`.

Answer (score 0):

You can plot this much easier without a four loop. Varying the coefficient inside the exponential moves the value and location of the peak.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def f(x, s):
   x**2 * np.exp(-s*x)

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y1 = f(x, 1.8)
y2 = f(x, 0.8)

plt.plot(x, y1, label='s=1.8')
plt.plot(x, y2, label='s=0.8')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: You solution looks good! Now the peak can moving along the Y axis. Is it possible to moving the peak along the X axis?

Comment: you can define a new function with a shifting parameter.
`def f(x, s, x0):   return (x-x0)**2 * np.exp(-s*(x-x0))`